# SoftLayer API retrieve total network devices from Hardware

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm using a ruby application along with the 'softlayer' gem to retrieve all the hardware (getHardware) and virtual machines (getVirtualGuests) associated to our accounts.  A question has come up about differentiating between network devices and machines.  I understand there are separate calls for getting certain network info and devices.  However, I'm wondering if network device information falls under the getHardware/getVirtualGuests results.  The "getHardware" call is returning several devices with a "Vyatta" operating system so can I assume "getHardware" retrieves all our network devices as well?  If this is true, is there a way I can reliably determine if a device is a network device other than the operating system value?  Example program:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => user, :api_key => api_key, :endpoint_url => endpoint_url, :timeout => 99999999)

account = client['Account'].object_mask("mask[virtualGuestCount,hardwareCount]").getObject()

bare_metal_machines_count = account["hardwareCount"]

for i in 0..(bare_metal_machines_count/30.0).ceil - 1
  list_of_baremetal_machines = client['Account'].result_limit(i*30,30).object_mask("mask[id, hostname, backendNetworkComponents[primarySubnet[podName]], hourlyBillingFlag, fullyQualifiedDomainName, provisionDate, datacenter[name], billingItem[recurringFee, associatedChildren[recurringFee], orderItem[description, order[userRecord[username], id]]], operatingSystem[id, softwareLicense[id, softwareDescription[longDescription]]], tagReferences[tagId, tag[name]], primaryIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress]").getHardware
  for x in 0..list_of_baremetal_machines.length - 1
    pp list_of_baremetal_machines[x]
  end
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call the getHardware method returns all bare metal servers, the reason why you are seeing several "Vyatta" servers is because they are bare metal servers as well,but with a "Vyatta" operating system.

you can use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch method to get and filter your data, that is the method that the portal uses.

here some examples:

List hardwares:

```
# Get Hardware list using SoftLayer_Search::advancedSearch
#
# Important manual pages:
# see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch
#
# license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
# author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

# Your SoftLayer API username.
SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Your SoftLayer API key.
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

# Softlayer API public endpoint
API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/'

softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: SL_API_USERNAME,
                                         api_key: SL_API_KEY,
                                         endpoint_url: API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT)

search_service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Search')

filter_data = 'networkGatewayMemberFlag:0 _objectType:SoftLayer_Hardware'

begin
  # Display Hardware items same as Portal > Device List
  result = search_service.advancedSearch(filter_data)
  puts 'Process finished successfully'
  p result
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e
end
```

List gateway members:

```
# Get Gateway Member list using SoftLayer_Search::advancedSearch
#
# Important manual pages:
# see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch
#
# license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
# author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

# Your SoftLayer API username.
SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Your SoftLayer API key.
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

# Softlayer API public endpoint
API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/'

softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: SL_API_USERNAME,
                                         api_key: SL_API_KEY,
                                         endpoint_url: API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT)

search_service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Search')

filter_data = 'networkGatewayMemberFlag:1 _objectType:SoftLayer_Hardware'

begin
  # Display Gateway Member items same as Portal > Device List
  result = search_service.advancedSearch(filter_data)
  puts 'Process finished successfully'
  p result
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e
end
```

List netscalers:

```
# Get Netscaler list using SoftLayer_Search::advancedSearch
#
# Important manual pages:
# see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch
#
# license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
# author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

# Your SoftLayer API username.
SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Your SoftLayer API key.
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

# Softlayer API public endpoint
API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/'

softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: SL_API_USERNAME,
                                         api_key: SL_API_KEY,
                                         endpoint_url: API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT)

search_service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Search')

filter_data = '_objectType:SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller'

begin
  # Display Netscaler items same as Portal > Device List
  result = search_service.advancedSearch(filter_data)
  puts 'Process finished successfully'
  p result
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e
end
```

List Firewalls:

```
# Get Firewall list using SoftLayer_Search::advancedSearch
#
# Important manual pages:
# see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch
#
# license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
# author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

# Your SoftLayer API username.
SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Your SoftLayer API key.
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

# Softlayer API public endpoint
API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/'

softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: SL_API_USERNAME,
                                         api_key: SL_API_KEY,
                                         endpoint_url: API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT)

search_service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Search')

filter_data = '_objectType:SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall'

begin
  # Display Firewall items same as Portal > Device List
  result = search_service.advancedSearch(filter_data)
  puts 'Process finished successfully'
  p result
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e
end
```

List all devices:

```
# Get all items from Device list.
#
# Important manual pages:
#
# see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch
# license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
# author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>

require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

# Your SoftLayer API username.
SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Your SoftLayer API key.
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

# Softlayer API public endpoint
API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/'

softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: SL_API_USERNAME,
                                         api_key: SL_API_KEY,
                                         endpoint_url: API_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT)

search_service = softlayer_client.service_named('SoftLayer_Search')

# The items with the following Device types should be displayed
# using the below filter:
# Bare Metal Server, Virtual Server, Firewall, Gateway Member, Netscaler,KVM/IP
filter_data = '_objectType:SoftLayer_Hardware,'\
    'SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest,SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall,'\
    'SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller '

begin
  # Display all items same as Portal > Device List
  result = search_service.advancedSearch(filter_data)
  puts 'Process finished successfully'
  p result
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e
end
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson.  From the getHardware() call I'm making is there a field I can look at that will reliably tell me if a device is a network device?  Rather than looking at the OS?  Or should I just incorporate the following filter?:

filter_data = 'networkGatewayMemberFlag:0 _objectType:SoftLayer_Hardware'

Comment: the script to list the hardware I sent you did not work? you can use the property networkGatewayMemberFlag to see if the device is a gateway or not, only the gatway servers will have that flag with 1 or true.

Comment: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server there you can see more information about the flag

Comment: Nelson, will the getNetworkHardware call also get all network devices?  Thanks again!

Comment: Edit to above comment -- looks like getNetworkHardware gets too much, individual network components maybe.  I'm wondering what calls I should make from here:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account

to get all the network devices.  I'd prefer to make specific calls for what I want rather than a large search call.  Thank you.

Comment: getNetwokHardware returns all the routers and switches on your account getHardware returns Bare metal servers. getNetwoksHardware returns the information like in the portal page https://control.softlayer.com/network/status/local